# Printing User Input/Multidimensional Array

Tags: java, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I apologize if this is a repeat question. I'm not sure what to look for.

This is for an assignment so I would really like a push in the right direction versus just getting the answer. The code is to repeatedly ask a user to enter a state name which returns the state bird and state flower. Once the user has entered "None," a summary prints out that contains the state, bird, and flower of each state the user entered. Currently, the summary only prints the information of the LAST state entered by the user.

I am sorry for the sloppy work. I'm only beginning to learn!

```
public class StateInformation {

    private String[][] stateInfo =  {
        {"Alabama", "Yellowhammer", "Camellia"},
        {"Alaska", "Willow Ptarmigan", "Alpine Forget-Me-Not"},
        {"Arizona" , "Cactus Wren", "Saguaro Cactus Blossom"},
        {"Arkansas", "Northern Mockingbird", "Apple Blossom"},
        {"California", "California Quail", "California Poppy"},
        {"Colorado", "Lark Bunting", "Rocky Mountain Columbine"},
        {"Connecticut", "American Robin", "Mountain Laurel"},
        {"Delaware", "Blue Hen Chicken", "Peach Blossom"},
        {"Florida", "Northern Mockingbird", "Orange Blossom"},
        {"Georgia", "Brown Thrasher", "Cherokee Rose"},
        {"Hawaii", "Nene", "{Pua Aloalo"},
        {"Idaho", "Mountain Bluebird", "Syringa"},
        {"Illinois", "Greater Prairie-Chicken", "Violet"},
        {"Indiana", "Northern Cardinal", "Peony"},
        {"Iowa", "Eastern Goldfinch", "Wild Rose"},
        {"Kansas", "Weatern Meadowlark", "Wild Native Sunflower"},
        {"Kentucky", "Northern Cardinal", "Goldenrod"},
        {"Louisana", "Brown Pelican", "Louisana Iris"},
        {"Maine", "Black-Capped Chickadee", "White Pine Cone and Tassel"},
        {"Maryland", "Baltimore Oriole", "Black-Eyed Susan"},
        {"Massachusetts", "Black-Capped Chickadee", "Mayflower"},
        {"Michigan", "American Robin", "Apple Blossom"},
        {"Minnesota", "Common Loon", "Pink and White Lady Slipper"},
        {"Mississippi", "Northern Mockingbird", "Magnolia"},
        {"Missouri", "Eastern Bluebird", "White Hawthorn Blossom"},
        {"Montana", "Western Meadowlark", "Bitterroot"},
        {"Nebraska", "Western Meadowlark", "Goldenrod"},
        {"Neveda", "Mountain Bluebird", "Sagebrush"},
        {"New Hampshire", "Purple Finch", "Pink Lady's Slipper"},
        {"New Jersey", "Eastern Goldfinch", "Violet"},
        {"New Mexico", "Greater Roadrunner", "Yucca"},
        {"New York", "Eastern Bluebird", "Rose"},
        {"North Carolina", "Northern Cardinal", "Dogwood"},
        {"North Dakota", "Western Meadowlark", "Wild Prairie Rose"},
        {"Ohio", "Northern Cardinal", "White Trillium"},
        {"Oklahoma", "Scissor-Tailed Flycatcher", "Mistletoe"},
        {"Oregon", "Western Meadowlark", "Oregon Grape"},
        {"Pennslyvania", "Ruffed Grouse", "Mountain Laurel"},
        {"Rhode Island", "Rhode Island Red Chicken", "Violet"},
        {"South Carolina", "Carolina Wren", "Yellow Jessamine"},
        {"South Dakota", "Ring-necked Pheasant", "American Pasque"},
        {"Tennessee", "Northern Mockingbird", "Passion Flower"},
        {"Texas", "Northern Mockingbird", "Ennis"},
        {"Utah", "California Gull", "Sego Lily"},
        {"Vermont", "Hermit Thrush", "Red Clover"},
        {"Virginia", "Northern Cardinal", "American Dogwood"},
        {"Washington", "Willow Goldfinch", "Coast Rhododendron"},
        {"West Virginia", "Northern Cardinal", "Rhododendron"},
        {"Wisconsin", "American Robin", "Wood Violet"},
        {"Wyoming", "Western Meadowlark", "Indian Paintbrush"},
    };//End array initialization

    public StateInformation() {
    }

    public String[][] getStateInfo(){
       return stateInfo;
    }

    public void setState(String[][] state) {
        this.stateInfo = stateInfo;
    }
}
//End of Class
```

Here is the second class:

```
//Second Class
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestStateInformation {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        StateInformation states = new StateInformation();   
        String [][] state = states.getStateInfo();  

        //Inserting scanner & variable. 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true) {
            //Prompt the user to input a state name.  
            System.out.println("Please enter a state or None to exit: ");
            //Read the state entered by user, including leading/trailing white spaces.
            String stateInfo = scanner.nextLine();

            //If loop to end if None is entered.
            if (stateInfo.equalsIgnoreCase("None")) {
                break;
            } else {
                int position = getStatePosition(state, stateInfo);

                if (position != -1) {
                    System.out.println("Bird: " 
                                    + getBird(position, state) 
                                    +'\n' + "Flower: " 
                                    + getFlower(position, state) + '\n');
                }

                if ((scanner.nextLine().equals("None"))) {
                        System.out.println("***** Thank you! *****" + '\n' 
                            + "A summary report for each State, Bird, and Flower is: "
                            + '\n' + getState(position, state)+ ", "
                            + getBird(position, state) + ", "+ getFlower(position, state)
                            + '\n' + "Please visit our site again!");
                }//end if loop for printing bird and flower of state entered by user.
            }//End else loop
        }//end if loop
    }//end while loop


    private static int getStatePosition(String state[][], String stateInfo) {
        for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
            if (stateInfo.equalsIgnoreCase(state[i][0])) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    //Creates the position of the state name into [0]
    private static String getState(int position, String [][] state) {
        return state[position][0];  
    }

    //Creates the position of the state bird into [1].
    private static String getBird(int position, String [][] state) {
        return state[position][1];
    }

    //Creates the position of the state bird into [2]
    private static String getFlower(int position, String [][] state) {
        return state[position][2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a summary of activity, you must store each state in a collection.  Here a Set is used to avoid duplicates.
Example code showing each state stored in a Set, then iterating the Set follows:

```
public class TestStateInformation {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    StateInformation states = new StateInformation();
    String[][] state = states.getStateInfo();
    // Inserting scanner & variable.
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Set<Integer> positions = new HashSet<Integer>();

    while (true) {
        // Prompt the user to input a state name.
        System.out.println("Please enter a state or None to exit: ");
        // Read the state entered by user, including leading/trailing white
        // spaces.
        String stateInfo = scanner.nextLine();

        // If loop to end if None is entered.
        if (stateInfo.equalsIgnoreCase("None")) {
            System.out.println(
                    "***** Thank you! *****" + '\n' + "A summary report for each State, Bird, and Flower is: \n");

            for (Integer p : positions) {
                System.out.println(getState(p, state) + ", " + getBird(p, state) + ", " + getFlower(p, state)
                                + '\n');
            }
            System.out.println("Please visit our site again!");
            break;
        } else {
            int position = getStatePosition(state, stateInfo);
            if (position != -1) {
                positions.add(position);
                System.out.println("New size=" + positions.size());
                System.out.println("Bird: " + getBird(position, state) + '\n' + "Flower: "
                        + getFlower(position, state) + '\n');
            }
        }
    }
}// end while loop
```

With sample output:

```
***** Thank you! *****
A summary report for each State, Bird, and Flower is: 

Alaska, Willow Ptarmigan, Alpine Forget-Me-Not

California, California Quail, California Poppy

Florida, Northern Mockingbird, Orange Blossom

Please visit our site again!
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be too far off. You're able to write out the info for each state, as requested, right - so all you're missing is a summary of those at the end?

What you need then is some kind of data-structure to let you store info about which states the user has asked about. All you need to store for each question then, is a number - namely the index of that state. If you are able to store all of those in a list, then at the end, you can simply loop over that list, and print out the relevant info for each of them.

Since a regular array like `String[]` will not be resizable, you'll probably want to use something like an `ArrayList<Integer>`  instead. Use that to store a new line of information in each time a user requests info about a new state.

*Note: This assumes you want a log of what the user has asked for; if you don't want repetitions of the same states when the user has in fact asked for the same state several times, you can use some implementation of Dictionary instead, which will allow only a single instance of each state to be included in the final list.*

Hope this was enough info to help you along...